# Peux-tu me dire ce qui paraît [Pourquoi pas apparaît ???] à l’écran?

Tags: différence

> [Il ne faut pas confondre les verbes paraître et apparaître. Dans la majorité des cas, on emploie paraître plutôt qu’apparaître.](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9Cb4HgM2LRLc.html)
>
> Le verbe paraître a le sens de « devenir visible » ou de « sembler » et s’emploie pour des faits habituels ou normaux :
>
> - [1.] La lune a commencé à **paraître** vers 18 h hier soir.
> - [2.]  Peux-tu me dire ce qui **paraît** à l’écran? (et non : apparaît)

##### [1.]

Remarquer que la phrase 1 manque de l'objurgation entre parenthèses « (et non : apparaît) ». Adonc, peux-je remplacer *paraître* par *apparaître* sans changer de sens ?

##### [2.]

Pourquoi ne peux-je pas remplacer **paraît** par **apparaît** ?

Je pense que **apparaît** sied, si je regarde un écran (d'ordinateur ou de télévision) et quelque chose de saugrenu  ***(ap?)paraît (lequel est correct ici)*** ? Par exemple, **apparaît** convenient pour :

2.1. ces messages d'erreur qui ***(s' ?)(ap ?)paraîssent*** sur une télévision ?

[image]

[image]

2.2. [ecran bleu de la mort](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cran_bleu_de_la_mort), ou logiciel espion qui ***(s' ?)(ap ?)paraît*** sur l'écran d’un ordinateur ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On dirait plutôt "puis-je" de nos jours ... Pas trop "adonc", et pas trop "sied" non plus :-)

Comment: @Frank Sage objurgation ! :-)

Comment: Pour indiquer qu'un être vivant fait son apparition, on peut utiliser les 2 verbes. Pour une chose, on choisira "apparaître". Dans "Chasseurs d’ours" (une nouvelle d’Alexandre Dumas), on peut lire :  *Effectivement, l’animal parut presque aussitôt au coin du
verger, s’avança en droite ligne vers ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La réponse qui suit est valable en français de France métropolitaine.

Le lien cité me semble sinon faux, ou du moins d’un prescriptivisme qui n’a pas tenu compte des évolutions de la langue. Le [dictionnaire de l’Académie Française, neuvième édition](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A2169), indique pour « apparaître » aussi bien le sens n°1 avec une notion d’immédiateté (*le magicien fait apparaître une pièce*) que le sens n°2 qui est au contraire graduel (*des fissures apparaissent sur la façade*).

Par ailleurs, dans le sens littéral de *devenir visible*, « paraître » appartient désormais à un registre de langue très soutenu. Le sens est compréhensible, mais on ne le trouvera plus que dans des contextes très particuliers (poésie, jargon technique, ou ironie dans un texte imitant un style ampoulé). Le terme à employer variera selon le contexte :

> <s>un message paraît à l’écran</s> -> un message s’affiche à l’écran

> <s>le soleil paraît à l’horizon</s> -> le soleil devient visible à l’horizon / le soleil se lève

> <s>monsieur X paraît au bal</s> -> monsieur X vient au bal / monsieur X se montre au bal

Dans le sens figuré, « paraître » est quasiment synonyme de « sembler » :

> Il paraît avoir vingt ans = il semble avoir vingt ans

> Il paraît fatigué = il semble fatigué

Je vois une légère différence de sens dans l’expression figée « il paraît que », où le locuteur se détache de ce qui suit, alors que « il semble que » indique un minimum de croyance personnelle :

> Il paraît qu’il trompe sa femme = Le bruit court qu’il trompe sa femme, je répète la rumeur mais en réalité je n’en sais rien.

> Il semble qu’il trompe sa femme = J’ai de bonnes raisons, à titre personnel, de croire qu’il trompe sa femme (même si je peux me tromper). [On s’attend, si ce n’est pas déjà fait, à ce que le locuteur avance une preuve de ce qu’il vient de dire.]

Answer (score 5):

Il semblerait que cette utilisation de ***paraître*** soit aujourd'hui possible en français canadien mais elle ne subsiste guère en France que dans des expressions plus ou moins figées comme ***Lorsque l'enfant paraît*** (Victor Hugo).

Aujourd'hui, *paraître* est surtout utilisé ici pour les publications, ex. :

> *Charlie Hebdo **paraît** tous les mercredis.* C'est une parution.

On ne dira pas *Charlie Hebdo **apparaît** tous les mercredis*, sauf s'il s'agit d'une apparition, un fait miraculeux :-)

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| La lune a commencé à **être visible** vers 18 h hier soir. | ✅✅ |
| La lune a commencé à **apparaître** vers 18 h hier soir. | ✅ |
| La lune a commencé à **paraître** vers 18 h hier soir. | ❓ |
|  |  |
| Peux-tu me dire ce qui **s'affiche** à l'écran ? | ✅✅ |
| Peux-tu me dire ce qui **apparaît** à l'écran ? | ✅ |
| Peux-tu me dire ce qui **paraît** à l'écran ? | ❓ |

Plutôt que la page du gouvernement du Canada citée dans la question (mise à jour [ici](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/paraitre-apparaitre)), mieux vaut se fier à [celle de la BDL de l'OQLF](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23852/le-vocabulaire/nuances-semantiques/difference-entre-paraitre-et-apparaitre), bien plus nuancée et conforme aux usages que l'on connaît en France.